# How to configure express and consign in heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I created a application using Express and Consign in node.js. Usually it works on the local machine and other places, is not the first time that I use this settings.

This is the code that I used to start the aplication:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const consign = require('consign');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const expressSession = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './app/views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app/public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator());

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'xxxxxx',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

consign()
    .include(path.join('app/routes'))
    .then(path.join('app/controllers'))
    .into(app);

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("To app is available in http://localhost:" + port);
});
```

The routes working normally and when I try to use at one routes file, like this:

```
module.exports = function (application) {
    application.get('/SomePathAtAPI', function (req, res) {
        application.app.controllers.file.func(application, req, res);
    });
}
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controllers' of undefined
     at /app/app/routes/home.js:5:25
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
     at session (/app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:454:7)
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
     at /app/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:291:5
     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Make sure your package.json is correct and checked in to your git repository.  I'm betting you didn't save `consign` as a dependency.

Comment: I have. I'm using the version 0.1.6

Comment: I have success modifing from "/app/app/routes/home.js"